# Limit login attempts with only Supabase and SolidJS

Tags: authentication, supabase

I'm building a web application using Supabase and SolidJS, so without a another back-end. I'm using the auth provided by Supabase for logging in users. I'm worried about brute-force attacks, though, since I cannot find an option to limit the number of log-in attempts through Supabase.

I was hoping that there was something I could use to trigger a database function when there was an unsuccesful log-in attempt, so I could keep track of the number of consecutive wrong passwords entered for a specific email (or user), which then would get reset to 0 when the right password was entered. However, there is nothing I can find in the auth schema tables. Now I'm wondering what to do. So far I've come up with the following options:

1. Only use a captcha service to stop bots from trying too often, which doesn't seem safe and is not really an option for me.
2. Switch to using a different auth service such as Auth0, which does limit login attempts
3. Switch to using only magic links: this might be annoying to users who prefer using password managers. Also, I'm not sure if I can switch off email + password use only and just keep using magic links using Supabase.

Am I missing something obvious here? Any recommendations for how to proceed?

Comment: Supabase auth has mitigations against various attacks including brute force attacks you are trying to protect your app against. That is one of the benefits of using Supabase auth that you get all these protection layers without having to configure it.

Comment: Could you expand on these mitigations? The only thing I've been able to find is this page on [rate limits](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/platform/going-into-prod#auth-rate-limits). However, it doesn't explicitly say anything about log-in attempts. It could be in the 'Verification requests' rate limit (360 requests per hour (with bursts up to 30 requests)), however they don't really specify what a 'verification request' is exactly: is this only when you try to log in or something else?

Comment: Here is the original PR that adds rate limiting to mitigate brute force attacks.  https://github.com/netlify/gotrue/pull/248/files Also, Supabase uses Supabase auth for its dashboard, so if it didn't have such a basic mitigation, we would already all be hacked by now.